# How to Modify Stored Procedure Paramter in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

So I have created a Stored Procedure and I'am linking it to crystal report.
My stored procedure has 2 Parameter StartDate AS DATIME and EndDate AS DATEIIME.

Everything is good, when I run the Crystal report it ask me the parameters and it's working pretty fine.

**The change I want to bring :**
So my question is that, is it possible to change the Paramter format. What do I mean by that ?
In Crystal, if you create a parameter DataType Date you can set the property 
**Allow Range Values** to TRUE ...

But the paramters that come from the Stored Procedure wont allow me to set those properties
Is there a way I can allow my parameter that I receive from the Stored Procedure to have a Range value when I run the CR ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Any one there to help me out ???

Comment: Is this even possible to do ?

Comment: Anyone that can help me out ???